# Spring Boot 3 form login - cannot complete the process

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring Boot (**3.0.5**) based project. Following [this guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html), I'm trying to integrate Spring Security (**6.0.2**), in order to implement a simple form login process.

SecurityFilterChain:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/auth/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(form -> form
                    .loginPage("/v1/view/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/v1/auth/login")
                    .permitAll()
            );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"))
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

This is the controller that "opens" the login page:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("v1/view")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

This is the controller that manages login data:

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @PostMapping(value = "login", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequestDTO requestDTO){
        log.debug("Login");
    }
}
```

This is the login page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Please Log In</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Please Log In</h1>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.</div>
<form th:action="@{/v1/auth/login}" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I access the login page (/v1/view/login) and after submitting credentials data, the application returns a 404 error page:

[image]

I expected it calls the /v1/auth/login controller, as I defined it as login processing URL, but it doesn't.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that you are successfully logged in, but redirected to non-existing login success page which is by default '/'. Try to add a new template **index.html** to the templates folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Main page</h1>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Something bad happened.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And generally for investigating such problems I recommend to switch on debug logging and look there. You can enable logging with the following settings:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: DEBUG
```

Or in case if you have application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework: DEBUG
```

Comment: How can I set this new template as success page?

Comment: You do not need to, it will be a default success page if you name it index.html. But if you need to set another page you may configure it in your WebSecurityConfig like this .loginPage("/v1/view/login").loginProcessingUrl("/v1/auth/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true).permitAll()